# Will my computer be able to run Windows 8 without UEFI?

Tags: bios, windows-8-preview, uefi

Will I be able to run windows 8 on my system, even though I am not using UEFI? Is there a work around if I don't want to use UEFI?

Comment: It wouldn't make sense for 90%+ of M$'s consumer base to buy the software!

Comment: UEFI has been in use even in Win7, Windows 8 just takes advantage of it more within the boot process to make it faster. I have a non-UEFI based laptop perfectly running the developer preview.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Yes. Windows 8 will support BIOS without UEFI.

> We will continue to support the legacy BIOS interface, but machines using the UEFI interface will have significantly richer capabilities.

The quote is from Microsoft's [Building Windows 8 Developers Blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20151201195412/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/b8/archive/2011/09/20/reengineering-the-windows-boot-experience.aspx) title: Reengineering the Windows boot experience. It was just posted yesterday.

Comment: UEFI will be required for any PC conforming to the "Windows 8 logo program" I assume this is for the OEM PC market....http://mjg59.dreamwidth.org/5552.html

Answer (score 2):

Actually it will support, windows 8 is being planned to work over UEFI BIOS. According to this [website](http://www.ghacks.net/2011/06/04/windows-8-video-demonstration-at-computex-2011/):

> "Mike’s words have caused some confusion in Germany, where popular
>   media outlets such as Heise reported that Windows 8 would only support
>   UEFI, a new interface between an operating system and platform
>   firmware, and not BIOS. This would mean that the majority of Windows
>   customers would not be able to upgrade to Windows 8, considering that
>   more than 99% of all users worldwide have a BIOS interface and not
>   UEFI."

And [this](http://news.softpedia.com/news/Windows-8-UEFI-Requirements-and-Security-Architecture-Sessions-at-IDF2011-220707.shtml):

> “Topics in this session include: wow a future platform would evolve
>   with advanced features in firmware using the latest UEFI protocol and
>   services; [and] technical details of the latest Windows* 8 platform
>   requirements including UEFI boot and security will be discussed.”
>
> The ‘Microsoft Windows 8 on Intel Architecture’ session “will provide
>   a glimpse into: the upcoming release of Microsoft’s next operating
>   system release Windows 8; [and] the work both companies are
>   undertaking to deliver this new compute experience.”

Even AMI(American Megatrend Inc) which produces BIOS already [annouced](http://www.thestreet.com/story/11247481/1/american-megatrends-announces-aptio-uefi-bios-support-for-windows-8-uefi-development-pc-at-build-conference.html) the UEFI support to Windows 8:

> "American Megatrends Announces Aptio UEFI BIOS Support For Windows 8,
>   UEFI Development PC At BUILD Conference"

Answer (score 2):

Two things, really - almost all new systems have UEFI, and windows 8 64 bit dev preview works fine on a system with a 'classic' bios - it runs really well on a 4 year old core 2 based system, and a good many test systems they use are bios based.

MS's design goals are for windows 8 to run on the same hardware windows vista and 7 does - and forcing a signed bootloader sort of goes against it.

I *do* see UEFI implimentations supporting additional features with respect to windows (lenovo already uses it for faster boot on their windows 7 systems).

UEFI/signed bootloaders might make sense on the arm versions, especially if MS has input on the hardware - especially if they are metro only.

Answer (score 1):

### We don't know.  Windows 8 hasn't been released yet.

Heck — it isn't even in beta yet.

All that people can tell you about is Windows Developer Preview, which **isn't Windows 8**.  And what they, or at least the subset of people without EFI firmware who have installed it on their machines, can tell you about that is that it does not *require* EFI firmware.  [Microsoft's stated hardware requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/apps/br229516) are that Windows Developer Preview, subject to various processor/RAM/disc space/graphics card minima, can be used on "the same hardware that powers Windows Vista and Windows 7".

Comment: Actually we do, see SgtOJ's answer below.