# Will Windows 8 install on MBR?

Tags: uefi, mbr, gpt, windows-8-preview

Will Windows 8 install on a disk which has an MBR partition scheme? In addition, can there be anything like MBR and UEFI? (Isn't it GPT + UEFI?)

Do the first Generation of Intel Core (i3,i5,i7) support UEFI or does the support start from Sandy Bridge upwards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question shows poor research so not +1ing it, but it's innocent enough so not -1ing either...

First part: You need to use GPT and UEFI together. EFI System Partition is only supported on GPT disk. You can also just format your disk as GPT (this is supported even for extremely old hardware) and not use UEFI; the PC BIOS should be able to boot from a GPT disk. I was doing this way back in the "Core 2 Duo" days.

Windows 8 will install on a MBR / PC BIOS system. See [Will my computer be able to run Windows 8 without UEFI?](https://superuser.com/questions/338103/will-my-computer-be-able-to-run-windows-8-without-uefi)

Second part: The earliest Intel CPUs (more accurately, motherboards) supporting UEFI were the Sandy Bridge as you said. So the Sandy Bridge and Ivy Bridge CPUs are the current production CPU generations supporting UEFI.

Comment: _The earliest Intel CPUs (more accurately, motherboards) supporting UEFI were the Sandy Bridge as you said._ Untrue. The HP 6730b, for instance, is a Core 2 laptop supporting UEFI.

Comment: There are edge-case exceptions to every rule of thumb.

Answer (score 2):

It's not elegant, but if you install Windows 7 (which will format as MBR by default) and then use the Windows 8 disc to *upgrade*, then MBR will be preserved.  I had to do this in order for Truecrypt to be able to encrypt the system drive on Windows 8.