# Setting Primary Partition As Active

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, windows-installation

Guy's i'm wondering why i can't set the Partition that i want (Drive C) as the Primary Partition, When i right click the Drive C in disk management tool it won't give me an option to set it as Primary partition? Can you please help me how to set A Partition as Primary? I already run  disk management tool as Administrator, i'm using windows 7. Thanks.

Comment: Define what you mean as "primary" partition please.  Are you confusing bootable with primary?

Comment: Your question doesn't make a lot of sense. Why don't you post a screen shot of the disks in the Disk Management console.

Answer (score 0):

If your Windows is installed on a non-primary partition (logical partition) there is no simple, one-click method for converting logical partition into primary. If you need your C: drive to be a primary partition you should reinstall your Windows. Also, if You want your whole Windows to be installed on a SINGLE PRIMARY PARTITION (instead of TWO), you can follow the steps described in my answer to: [How can I use TrueCrypt under windows 8.1?](https://superuser.com/questions/669026/how-can-i-use-truecrypt-under-windows-8-1/) in section flagged as 2.